# why django model instance naming object itself

Tags: django, django-admin

I don`t know this the right title to ask. And i have not enough reputation to post image.

models.py

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
```

And i registered models to admin

in the admin page i added artist name no issue. Then in the album section in the drop down it`s showing like album object instead of what i given the artist name. what is that for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't know you want to use `artist_name` as a string representation of the Artist object. You need to add a [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#unicode) (or `__str__` on Python 3) method to your Artist model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.artist_name
```

Comment: can you tell me if i want to display the filefield object in admin ?

Comment: if i do what you are suggested i got error 'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: You need to return unicode data from `__unicode__`. FileField contents isn't unicode, it's a FieldFile objects, so you need to convert it to unicode in the `__unicode__` method. Fortunately, it converts easily just by doing `unicode(self.your_file_field)`. You can also return self.your_file_field.url, or represent it as a string any other way you like.

Answer (score 1):

Even better if you want to be in sync with python 2 and 3:

At the top of your models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

then before your class:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class YourClass(models.Model):
```

And then:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title
```